# Download pdf with retrofit 2.3 with webView from moodle - Android

Tags: php, android, cookies, retrofit2, moodle

I am loading a `url` in `webView`, the webSite is `php` base `moodle`.In the webView is a lot `*.pdf` and I need to download those `pdfs` but I can't and just download login page .
Notice :

1- I login to webSite in `webView` then I get the `cookies` like bellow :

```
urlListClassWebView.setWebViewClient(new CustomBrowsers());             
urlListClassWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);         
urlListClassWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
urlListClassWebView.clearHistory();
urlListClassWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);       
urlListClassWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
urlListClassWebView.loadUrl(url);
urlListClassWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                    @Override
                    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                        if (url.contains(".pdf")) {
                            String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

2- Then I send `cookies` to `moodle` like bellow with retrofit 2.3 :

```
@Headers({
        "Referer: http://xx.xx.xx/course/view.php?id=2484",
        "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SM-G920F Build/NRD90M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/62.0.3202.84 Mobile Safari/537.36",
        "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1"
})
@POST
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<ResponseBody> downloadFile(@Url String url,
                                @Field("_ga") String _ga,
                                @Field("MoodleSession") String MoodleSession,
                                @Field("MOODLEID1_") String MOODLEID1_,
                                @Field("loglevel") String loglevel);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved my problem :

1-First I get `cookies` the I create them like : `aa=546345; bb=dfjds65;`

2-Then I pass it with retrofit like bellow :

```
@POST
Call<ResponseBody> downloadFile(@Url String url,
                                @Header("Cookie") String sessionIdAndToken);
```